# profit for products

Tags: sql

I d like to create a query gives me Overall revenue per product greater than 150000 in in descending order.   You can see my tables and desired output on images I have added

Comment: Really, you should take the trouble to put the data and desired results directly in the question.  You can format tables by putting four spaces at the beginning of a line.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats not clear from your question is how you want to calculate revenue. Assuming that revenue per product is calculated as unit price x quantity from the Order_Items table:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(unit_price * quantity) AS revenue
FROM Order_Items
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(unit_price * quantity) > 150000
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was what ı looked for.